# Why does the Connection close without a response Heroku deployed nodejs app

Tags: node.js, heroku, sails.js

I'm trying to deploy a **nodeJS** app connected to a **clearDB** mysql database but I keep getting a **H13** error and **503** status when I open the app. I can run the application locally through **heroku** local web, and can access the database and populate it. What am I missing to get it to work?

```
2018-08-26T00:29:43.893927+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=dry-sierra-30617.herokuapp.com request_id=73aa3442-d16e-433a-ae77-787ad60c4393 fwd="24.85.26.213" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=0ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2018-08-26T00:29:44.604773+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=dry-sierra-30617.herokuapp.com request_id=8a00d2fd-3296-4c81-979a-bab1b97cd9cd fwd="24.85.26.213" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occured because the application was using an expired SSL certificate. Removing the certificate from /config/ssl.js allowed the connection to occur. I then used Heroku's SSL certificate service to secure the site.